# linearly ranking values from 0:10 in r

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(G = c(NA, NA, -1.01182174807081, -1.01182174807081, 
-1.01182174807081, -1.03501949560312, -1.03501949560312, -1.03501949560312, 
-1.01189555194367, -1.01189555194367, -1.01189555194367, -1.03208191284692, 
-1.03208191284692, -1.03208191284692, -1.00007825695672, -1.00007825695672, 
-1.00007825695672, -1.03027247563088, -1.03027247563088, -1.03027247563088, 
-0.999632960176179, -0.999632960176179, -0.999632960176179, -0.998570208055593, 
-0.998570208055593, -0.998570208055593, -0.975978344319463, -0.975978344319463, 
-0.975978344319463, -0.984342844790316, -0.984342844790316, -0.984342844790316, 
-0.998450245287518, -0.998450245287518, -0.998450245287518, -1.11255680134788, 
-1.11255680134788, -1.11255680134788, -1.14437105346841, -1.14437105346841, 
-1.14437105346841, -1.24738311047776, -1.24738311047776, -1.24738311047776, 
-1.28564738896258, -1.28564738896258, -1.28564738896258, -1.30225611704836, 
-1.30225611704836, -1.30225611704836, -1.17181860494129, -1.17181860494129, 
-1.17181860494129, -1.15687952410288, -1.15687952410288, -1.15687952410288, 
-1.12078874426169, -1.12078874426169, -1.12078874426169, -1.12194837414298, 
-1.12194837414298, -1.12194837414298, -1.1119085686834, -1.1119085686834, 
-1.1119085686834, -1.11460209275208, -1.11460209275208, -1.11460209275208, 
-1.14030482631462, -1.14030482631462, -1.14030482631462, -1.25693845068723, 
-1.25693845068723, -1.25693845068723, -1.29636270710907, -1.29636270710907, 
-1.29636270710907, -1.28630939351124, -1.28630939351124, -1.28630939351124, 
-1.34123496736839, -1.34123496736839, -1.34123496736839, -1.30208113084414, 
-1.30208113084414, -1.30208113084414, -1.27472858798502, -1.27472858798502, 
-1.27472858798502, -1.2601313178257, -1.2601313178257, -1.2601313178257, 
-1.25435070950356, -1.25435070950356, -1.25435070950356, -1.25446776571291, 
-1.25446776571291, -1.25446776571291, -1.31782396761758, -1.31782396761758, 
-1.31782396761758, -1.32404892123336, -1.32404892123336, -1.32404892123336, 
-1.35533362583485, -1.35533362583485, -1.35533362583485, -1.32224476611552, 
-1.32224476611552, -1.32224476611552, -1.37165859726789, -1.37165859726789, 
-1.37165859726789, -1.32061051911721, -1.32061051911721, -1.32061051911721, 
-1.26156328360682, -1.26156328360682, -1.26156328360682, -1.26156328360682, 
-1.26156328360682, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -123L))
```

What I want is to rank every value 0 to 10, where 0 should equal the highest value (-0.9759783) and 10 should be the lowest value (-1.37166). Everything in between should be ranked linearly so that, for example, -1.25693845068723 should yield 7.1 and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `scales::rescale(-df$G, to = c(0,10))`

Comment: If you have more than 11 unique values, how can you "rank" them from 0 to 10? I assume you mean "scale".